# Как побороть ошибку "Ожидалось имя процедуры или функции"?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Не могу никак вывести функцию, все время что-то не так.

[image]

Вот мой код, отметил строку текстом с ошибкой:

```
var
  x,y: real;
  n:byte;
begin
  writeln('ввести x');
  readln(x); 
  if x<=-05 then
  begin
    y:=cos(sqrt(exp(yln(1/5)(abs(x+ln(abs(x)))))));  // <<<--- Ожидалось имя процедуры или функции
    n:=1
  end
  else if(x>-0,5)and(x<=0,5)then
  begin 
    y:=cos(exp(abs(x+ln(abs(x))))); 
    n:=2 
  end
  else 
  begin 
    y:=exp((yln(1/3)))(exp(x))(sqrt(x+1))-pi; 
    n:=3
  end;
  writeln('x=',x:6:2,'y=',y:6:2,'n=',n:3);
end.
```

Comment: Приведите хотя бы какой-то код, пусть с ошибками - там поможем.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, в виде текста, плиз.

Comment: "Всё время что-то не так" - это так всегда, когда изучаешь програмирование.... Уточните что не так у вас сейчас, и перенесите текст программы в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавила, спасибо

Comment: В качестве десятичного разделителя должны использоваться точки, а не запятые. И местами этот разделитель пропущен.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster, ведь достаточно распространённая проблема у новичков - зачем закрывать и минусовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не минусовал. А вот флаг за закрытие я бы поставил, за то что не обозначена проблема. Теперь ТС хотя бы скрином ее показал, флажок не ставлю.

Answer (score 3):

Почти во всех языках программирования нельзя опускать знак умножения. А в приведённом коде на его месте даже пробелов нет.

**Во всех местах, где подразумевается умножение, должен стоять символ `*`.**

Вторая ошибка заключается в том, что в числах в качества разделителя дробной части использована запятая: `0,5`, **а должна быть точка: `0.5`**.

Comment: в вольфрам альфа и математике можно. Если знак вопроса именно это означает.

Comment: @pavel, да, он означал, что я не могу вспомнить язык, в котором можно.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём описывать первую формулу:

1-1)  `y := x*x` — это x²

1-2)  `y := x*x + sqr()` — это квадрат для тангенса

1-3)  `y := x*x + sqr( sin() / cos() )` — это собственно тангенс, которого нет в паскале

1-4)  в скобочки sin и cos нужно добавить `(x+pi)/2`

Как итог, первая формула получилась такой:

`y := x*x + sqr( sin((x + pi) / 2) / cos((x + pi) / 2) )`

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Вторая:

2-1)  `y := cos()` — это понятно итак

2-2)  `y := cos( exp( ln() / 5))` — корень пятой степени

2-2)  `y := cos( exp( ln( abs(x + ln(abs(x))) ) / 5))` — тут просто

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Третья:

3-1)  `y := exp( ln() / 3)` — корень третьей степени

3-2)  `y := exp( ln( x + exp(x) * sqrt(x + 1) - pi ) / 3)` — добавить только то, что под корнем

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Вот и вся программа:

```
var
  x,y: real;
begin
  writeln('ввести x');
  readln(x); 
  if x <= -0.5 then
    y := x*x + sqr( sin((x + pi) / 2) / cos((x + pi) / 2) )
  else if x > +0.5 then
    y := exp( ln(x + exp(x) * sqrt(x + 1) - pi) / 3 )
  else  { -0.5 < x <= +0.5 }
    y := cos( exp(ln( abs(x + ln(abs(x))) ) / 5) );
  writeln('y(', x:6:2, ') = ', y:6:2);
end.
```